# link de paginación no funciona

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy tratando de hacer un paginado y casi lo consigo, pero cuando cambio de una página para otra no funciona, sin embargo cuando lo hago de forma manual sí. Cuando doy click en el link en el navegador me muestra `&page=40`, y manual mente solo pongo `40`. No se porqué hace eso.

**mi Controlador**

```
function Test ($value){
if($value =='1'){
  $config['per_page'] = 20;
  $config['num_links'] = 10;
  $config["total_rows"] = $this->db->get('normas')->num_rows();
  $data['query'] = $this->db->get('normas', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(4));
  $this->pagination->initialize($config);
  $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

 $this->load->view('template/general_template/template', $data);
    }
}
```

**Mi vista**

```
<?php 
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    echo '<p>'. $row->norma.'</p>';
    } 
echo $links;
?>
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sólo tenia que cambiar en mi configuración `$config['page_query_string'] = FALSE;`

> $config[‘page_query_string’] = TRUE;
>
> By default, the pagination library assume you are using URI Segments, and >constructs your links something like:
>
> http:/example.com/index.php/test/page/20
>   If you have $config['enable_query_strings'] set to TRUE your links will >automatically be re-written using Query Strings. This option can also be >explicitly set. Using $config['page_query_string'] set to TRUE, the pagination >link will become:
>
> http:/example.com/index.php?c=test&m=page&per_page=20

Encontré esto en la documentación de Codeigniter 3
[Documentación CodeIgniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html)

Comment: Seria bueno que agregaras un ejemplo de lo que has encontrado, asi tu respuesta sera mas explicita para futuros usuarios que busquen una respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez sea que te falta la configuración del parámetro base_url, las veces que he usado la páginación siempre lo pongo, `$config['base_url']` indicando la dirección que será utilizada en la paginación con barra final tipo `base_url().'paginacion/esta/'`

Si esto no te funciona podrías indicar las dos url que mencionas que aparecen completas para tener una mayor idea, la del enlace y la manual.

Comment: gracias, ya me funciona, solo tenia que cambiar en mi configuración `$config['page_query_string'] = FALSE;`, yo lo tenia en TRUE, pero ahora tengo otro problema que no me sale el **First**

Comment: Con first que quieres decir que no te sale el primer número de la paginación?